# Symfony2: kernel.request, onKernelRequest not loading

Tags: php, symfony

I mostly using in each bundle kernel.request and everything is working find, but not in one.

The services.yml looks like below:

```
services:
    crm.addressbook.country_manager:
        class: CRM\AddressBookBundle\Country\CountryManager
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.dynamic_entity_manager ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

and the CountryManager:

```
namespace CRM\AddressBookBundle\Country;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class CountryManager {

    protected $em;
    protected static $country;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest()
    {
        $this->loadCountry();
    }

    private function loadCountry()
    {
        $country = $this->em->getRepository('CRMAddressBookBundle:CountryLang')->findAll();

        foreach($country as $row)
        {
            self::$country[$row->getCountry()->getId()] = $row->getName();
        }
    }

}
```

Does anyone knows what can be wrong? I am not getting any errors. It is just not starting the code...

Comment: Try giving it more priority: `{ name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 255 }`. Nonetheless, it should appear in your profiler status bar.

Comment: no, that also didn't worked

Comment: Is it displayed in the profiler, listeners section? It should appear there. If not, maybe you are not registering properly your listener, or another one is stopping the propagation, which sounds strange but plausible.

Comment: does the service exists in the container when running `app/console container:debug`? Otherwise, you service config file isn't loaded correctly.

Comment: @WouterJ I have checked by running `app/console container:debug` and it is not there. I have added to `imports` in config.yml the line `- { resource: "@CRMAddressBookBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }` and it is working. Is there any other, better way to include all services straight away from all bundles?

Comment: hmm...when I have added this line then onKernelRequests from other bundles are not loading..even when I have also added them into config.yml

Comment: alright, I have sort out this. The problem was with the SQLFilter which was running before my onKernelRequest. I have changed in config.yml to disable the filter and in onKernelRequest enable it.

Comment: "is there any other, better way to include all services straight away from all bundles?" - Yes, by loading them in the bundle extension. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#creating-an-extension-class